# Can I reduce the size of my catalog_product_index_eav table or increase my indexing speed?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, reindex

In Magento 1.9.2.4 table catalog_product_index_eav contains 3.802.998 records and catalog_product_index_eav_idx contains 2.447.411 records. The sizes of other tables are 100000 records or less, normal sizes I think.

Reindexing table catalog_product_attributes takes a lot of time in the CLI, more then 10 minutes or fails because losing the mysql connection.

I think the big size of table catalog_product_index_eav is related to taking a lot of time indexing Product Attributes.

There are no files in the var/locks directory. In my magento test environment I have truncated table catalog_product_index_eav and reindexing again. Table catalog_product_index_eav stays empty and indexing takes a lot of time.

I have 8GB mysql memory with mysql server mariaDB on Ubuntu.

Is there a way to reduce the size of catalog_product_index_eav or speed up indexing?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to speed up indexing by deleting the foreign key `FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT_PROCESS_ID_INDEX_PROCESS_PROCESS_ID` from the table `index_process_event`.